# Can I say that Monad makes it possible to see some types as isomorphic?

Tags: haskell, monads, isomorphic

`Monad` can pass `Just [1,2]`, which is a different type from what the original `length` function takes, to `>>= return . length`.

```
Just [1,2] >>= return . length
```

Can I say that `Monad` makes it possible to see `Maybe [a]` as isomorphic with `[a]` on length using `(>>=, return)`? (Of course they are not really isomorphic.)

Can I choose the term "isomorphic" this situation?

Comment: I would be careful using *isomorphic* on that situation. Perhaps one can say "almost isomorphic". `Maybe a` is not isomorphic with `a` but `Maybe a` excluding `Nothing` is isomorphic to `a`.

Comment: Yes. that is my reason to use term "isomorphic". because `Monad` take `Nothing` out from `Maybe` and then pass it to length function with extracting `Just`. (I don't explain real process but just concept.)

Comment: Rather than "tak[ing] `Nothing` out of `Maybe`" it's usually better to think of it as bringing `length` into `Maybe`, with `(>>=)` specifying what should happen in the `Nothing` case, in which there is nothing to apply `length` to.

Comment: While this is a different topic, you might be interested in the fact that `length` is a *monoid homomorphism* going from list types to the monoid for `Int` addition. This is shown by the two facts `Sum (length []) = Sum 0` and that if `xs` and `ys` are lists, then `Sum (length (xs <> ys)) = Sum (length xs) <> Sum (length ys)` , where `Sum` is a newtype wrapper that causes `<>` to act like addition (on the RHS, here). If you're interested, there's a paper on using monoid homomorphisms to design a library [here](https://repository.upenn.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1773&context=cis_papers)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What your example ultimately illustrates is that `Maybe` is a functor: if you have some `f :: a -> b`, you can use `fmap` to turn it into `fmap f :: Maybe a -> Maybe b` [in a way that preserves identities and composition](https://wiki.haskell.org/Typeclassopedia#Laws). Monads are functors, with `\f m -> m >>= return . f` being the same as `fmap f m`. In your case, we have the `length` function being transformed by the `Maybe` functor.

> can I choose term "isomorphic" this situation?

Not really. `fmap` for `Maybe` is not an isomorphism. An isomorphism requires there being a two-sided inverse that undoes it, which in this case would be something like:

```
unFmapMaybe :: (Maybe a -> Maybe b) -> (a -> b)

-- For it to be a two-sided inverse to `fmap`, we should have:
unFmapMaybe . fmap = id
fmap . unFmapMaybe = id
```

However, there are no `(Maybe a -> Maybe b) -> (a -> b)` functions, as there is no way to obtain a `b` result if the input `Maybe a -> Maybe b` function gives out a `Nothing`. While there are specific functors whose `fmap` is an isomorphism (`Identity` is one example), that is not the case in general.

Comment: Informally this is lifting a function, rather than expressing any isomorphism. `fmap` lifts a function from `[a]` to functions from `Maybe [a]`

Comment: Functors like `(->)` or `Dict` that you `unmap` are called [`FullyFaithful`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hask-0/docs/Hask-Functor-Faithful.html)

Comment: @Iceland_jack Nice! I don't think I had seen that module before. For the benefit of future readers (as those haddocks aren't the easiest thing to read), it's worth mentioning here that the `(->)` there isn't the function `Functor` (`(->) a` for some `a`). Rather, it amounts to the function profunctor, which, in this encoding, takes `f :: b -> a` (seen as a Hask^op morphism) to `(. f) :: (a -> c) -> b -> c` (seen as a natural transformation from `(->) a` to `(->) b`).

Answer (score 5):

`[a]` is isomorphic to the [quotient type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_type) of `Maybe [a]` with `Nothing` and `Just []` considered equivalent. Alternatively it is isomorphic to `Maybe (NonEmpty a)`, which simply eliminates the `Just []` case.

In other words, `[a]` can be factorized as a composition of the `Maybe` and `NonEmpty` functors.

A result of this is that you can lift any function on `NonEmpty a` to a function on `[a]`:

```
liftEmptyable :: (NonEmpty a -> r) -> [a] -> Maybe r
liftEmptyable _ [] = Nothing
liftEmptyable f (x:xs) = Just $ f (x:|xs)
```

Not sure that actually has much to do with your question though. As duplode answered, you don't really do anything but a simple functor mapping. We could at most elaborate that the monad laws ensure that the `fmap` really behaves as if `length` acted directly on the contained list:

```
Just [1,2] >>= return . length
  ≡ return [1,2] >>= return . length  -- def. of `Monad Maybe`
  ≡ return (length [1,2])             -- left-identity monad law
```